# Joomla 2.5 Submit Testing

Tags: joomla2.5, form-submit

i have the test Componente "Hello Wolrd".

I want this Code, to embed in Joomla.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 echo "Auf Button gedrückt";
}
else
{
?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

How do I put this on?

Thanks, for your Help

Comment: If it's going to be something simple, you might want to consider developing a module which will be much easier. If you're sure you need a component, then you should look at the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component)

Comment: Thanks... I have a Test Function.

Comment: Thanks... I have a Test Function, in model.php. 

 `function test()
 {
  $post = JRequest::get('post');

  return $post;
 }`

but how do I get the variable in the default.php?

the default.php:

`<?php
if(isset($post))
{
 echo "Auf Button gedrückt";
}
else
{
?>
<form action="index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=updhelloworld" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_helloworld" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="updhelloworld.submit" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>

<?php
}
?>`

Comment: everything is explained in the Documentation link I sent you. read through all the pages to get a clear overview of how data is processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to add functionality in joomla. All you have to do is start from joomla documentation.If you wanted to make a component like this then this tutorial is what you want -

> http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

It's better to develop component in mvc format, because then you will be able to modify other joomla components/third party components as joomla is now in MVC format.

> Find more tutorial on component/module development by google.com.That's all what you need to  get started